# How to redirect www.example.com to example.com using nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to make my nginx server to redirect any www request to non-www. On the nginx server, I run React application on port 3003 using Docker.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3003; # 8030 is the port the Docker container is running on
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of searching, I found the solution:

```
location / {
    if ($http_host ~* "^www.example.com"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 redirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($host = 'www.yoursite.com' ) {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://yoursite.com/$1  permanent;
}
```

Add this to your server directive and change the website URL.

Comment: hello! Thanks for help! Unfortunantly, www still works :(

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `map` instead of `if` to extract part of the `$host` value:

```
map $host $tld {
    default $host;
    '~^www\.(?<domain>.*)$' $domain;
}
```

In this case, the `map` directive extracts the value of `$tld`, which doesn't contain the `www.` part of the URL.

Comment: unfortunantly, when i apply this code. It compiles with errors